# Can SVN ignore local changes to a file until a newer modification?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Some of my current code files have a few lines changed for test purposes (a different constant value or some commented-out line). It doesn't seem like something I should commit as it's not a proper change to the code, just temporary. Yet, the files keep showing up as changed when checking for changes (quite normal!)

This wouldn't be so bad if they never changed otherwise (I could use a changeset), but a few times now, I've had to change these files for other reasons, with stuff that I *want* to commit.

I do know about Restore After Commit and this is not a question about how to commit partial files. My issue is that since the files show up as changed all the time, I never notice when they finally contain some pertinent change.

Any trick to keep the files out of the way until they contain pertinent changes?

I was thinking something like "ignore these changes", where SVN would only show the file as changed if they contained changes *other* than the initial set of changes. Some sort of... local temporary commit, if that makes sense?

Comment: Not sure whether I understand your use case. If they show up as *unchanged*, won't it be even more easy to forget when they actually need to be committed? I've been happily using changelists for this purpose.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: not if they appear as *changed* again with any new modification. 1) File is changed, 2) User says "I'll never commit these changes, forget this". File may still be listed but clearly apart from others. 3) File is changed again. File appears as modified as usual. User may repeat the cycle indefinitely potentially.

Comment: Ah... You want a sort of per-line status. That reminds me of git. There's nothing remotely similar in Subversion and I don't believe it's even planned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some sort of... local temporary commit

Subversion is not DVCS, you can't have anything locally stored. But you can commit your temporary changes into (semi-private) branch and return to work with trunk's version (removing branch-specific changes)

Comment: I've thought of this but am unsure. I'd feel like I'm "dirtying" the repository... which is probably silly on my part. Also, would this be practical with "single file" branches of sorts? If that's even a good thing.

Comment: @leokhorn - Subversion repository isn't nice showcase, it's backend of development process. "Clean trunk" is sufficient constraint, all other must help and improve working process. Branch even for one-line change in one file is OK (in companies with brain-powered management)